# How to get creation datetime of a blob file from Azuredatafactory or Azure Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]I can fetch lastmodified file from get metadata activity but the requirement is the creation date of the file .I can see no option to fetch that in Azure Data Factory . Besides I need to fetch:

```
First row from   fileCreationDateTime --- Descending Order. So i need the CreationDateTime functionality as LastModified .
```

As shown in the picture , there are two things CREATION TIME and LAST MODIFIED . So i need to fetch all the creationtimes and sort it to decending and pick the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Web Activity in ADF and make a call to [Get Blob REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) which will return the blob creation date in Web activity Response headers section, and you can use that value as per your requirement.

Get Blob REST API sample URI: https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob

Ref document: [Get Blob - Response Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob#response-headers)

[image]

You can capture the value of Blob creation datetime from the REST API response headers in ADF using below dynamic expression:

```html
@activity('WebGetBlobDetails').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['x-ms-creation-time']
```

Here is a sample demo.  I have used the hardcoded bearer token in the headers for a quick demo, but you can automate and pass dynamically by having another web activity to get the bearer token before `WebGetBlobDetails` activity.

Sample GIF:

[image]

Comment: This is fine for one file /blob . My actual reqyirement is to fetch the latest created file from a group of files , that means i need to pass the seperate SAS token for each file ,and do a GetMetadata followed by foreach. Question is like how to genrate SAS tokens for each file dynamically and is there any other way so that only One token is used for all files.l?